# Should you have two signup forms on a beta page?

Tags: website-design, conversion

On a startup's beta page, is it a good idea to have two signup forms?

--- Tagline

--- Signup form

--- Content

--- More content

--- An identical signup form

The two forms are never both visible at the same time.
The goal of having two forms is increasing conversion - one immediate call to action, and another one after the user has read all the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  recent example I saw two Sign up buttons was [Mailchimp](http://mailchimp.com) site. The reason for this solution is simple: all the visitors divided into two groups. Ones who know the service (from ads, articles, etc.) and want to register immediately. They'll probably use top button.

The Sign up button at the bottom behind value proposition is for those who were less sure in registering from the beginning and needed more info before taking decision.
[image]

Pay attention, they are buttons, not forms which scare users and waste page space! So each page has goals. On the landing page just be persuasive enough to make a user click the button. On the register page provide good form experience to not lose a client.

Answer (score 1):

How big is the signup form? If it's as simple as - Name, Email, Password - why not just make it always visible (sticky) on the page? It's at the top, they begin scrolling down, it sticks to the top. Or put it in a fixed footer or a sidebar. They can fill it out whenever they like. There's obviously nothing wrong with showing it twice, but if the idea is to minimize the effort necessary to fill out the form, it seems making it always present on the screen would do that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not wrong to have two identical call to actions if the value prop contents are long. However, I'd argue that forms are more than just a simple "call to action" since it requires more work for them and it might look too repetitive. Therefore I'd recommend displaying only a sign up link/button and direct them to a form afterward.

From a user's perspective, they most likely will not fill out form/click on the link if they don't get or like the product regardless of where you placed the call to action. If they do like the product after scrolling down and read through the content, they'll most likely scroll back up and sign up even thought there is no call to action at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of our productboard landing page, signup form is just a field for email address and we have it twice on the landing page and then again on every other page. Looking at our analytics here is the breakdown of where people sign up from:

1. Top of home page 68.94%
2. Footer of home page 15.53%
3. Pricing page 9.47%
4. Feature overview page 4.17%
5. About us page 1.89%

Also, we have done something very different and something our beta users really loved for the whole beta signup process. I've written up a blog post about it here: http://blog.productboard.com/post/126503384615/how-we-designed-a-very-different-memorable-and

[image]